Find the frequence of the string "BBA" in an array of characters using recursion in Java
Exercise on recursive methods:
Use the technique divide-and-conquer to write a Java method
int findBBA(char[] array, int left, int right) that returns the frequency of the
string ‘‘BBA’’ in the array spanning from left to right.
Hi everyone, I've managed to solve this kind of problem only when the sequence
was two characters/digits long (for example the number of occurrences of "01" in
an array of integers or "BA" in one of characters).
I've done some research but I can't find a solution for this problem. Could anyone help please?
Thank you very much.
public static int _findBBA(char[] a, int l, int r) {
    
    if(l+2 >= r)

        return 0;
    
    int mid = (l+r)/2;
    
    int find1 = _findBBA(a, l, mid);
    int find2 = _findBBA(a, mid, r);
    
    int res = find1 + find2;
    
    if(a.length % 2 == 0) {
    
        if(a[mid-1] == 'B' && a[mid] == 'B' && a[mid+1] == 'A')
            res++;
        
        if(a[mid-2] == 'B' && a[mid-1] == 'B' && a[mid] == 'A')
            res++;
    }
    
    else
        if(a[mid-1] == 'B' && a[mid] == 'B' && a[mid+1] == 'A')
            res++;
    
    return res;
}


You have over complicated this task. Declare and initialize res to 0 at the very beginning of your method:
int res = 0;

You have a left and a right parameter for your recursive method. Since they're not declared as final you can obviously use and modify their values within the method. There is no need for a mid variable since left + 1 will give you that information.
You should really only need one main if block in your method and another if block to check if right has gone beyond the array.length - 1:
if (array[left] == 'B' && array[left + 1] == 'B' && array[right] == 'A') {
    System.out.println("BBA sequence found at array index: " + left);
    res = 1;
}

// Increment parameter values so to continue checking the array:
left += 1;   // Increment `left` by 1
right += 1;  // Increment `right` by 1

/* If `right` has not gone beyond array.length - 1 then recursively 
   call this method again with new argument values.      */
if (right <= array.length -1) {
     res = res + findBBA(array, left, right);
    // or:  res += findBBA(array, left, right);
}
return res;

To use you might have something like this:
char[] array = {'D','B','B','A','C','B','B','A','F','G','A','B','B','C','B','B','A'};
int fnd = findBBA(array, 0, 2);
System.out.println("BBA sequence is within the array at " + fnd + " locations.");

The Console output should look something like this:
BBA sequence found at array index: 1
BBA sequence found at array index: 5
BBA sequence found at array index: 14
BBA sequence is within the array at 3 locations.

